# Windows Security Center increases run time of programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, security-center

Whenever I open `PyCharm` program in Windows 10, Windows Security Center starts analysing it and it slows down the loading process for opening this program. Is there any way that Windows Security Center would ignore this program whenever it runs?

Comment: Which version of Windows? What did you try so far?

Comment: @ArtGertner Win10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security

1. Go to Start  > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection.
2. Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings, and then under Exclusions, select Add or remove exclusions.

[image]

3. Select Add an exclusion, and then select from files, folders, file types, or process. The exclusion will apply to subfolders within a folder as well.

More detailed explanation with screenshots here:
https://winaero.com/blog/exclusions-windows-defender-windows-10/

Comment: I added the folder of this program to the exclusions but I can still see in Task Manager that it is analyzing it again.

Comment: You may want to add "process" rather than "folder". And specify executable name (check in task manager beforehand).